# function is not called upon submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, web

I created this form to submit some info to the server-side. The form is in HTML/CSS and I am using AngularJS latest version. I also made sure that the button is inside the form. I know its most common mistake. But still, it's not working. The function I want to call is "onAddEditTenantSubmitForm" which is also assigned to state as well. I have checked it using the Chrome browser and marked line number 87. but it does not trigger. Also there is no error in the console too.

Below is the link to JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jLtsuonx/

'''
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.controller('MultiTenantController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'TenantServices', function ($scope, $filter, TenantServices) {

```
    var uibModal = null;

    var test = "Multi Tenat Controller";

    var state = {
        tenantModel: {
            addedOn: '',
            connectionString: '',
            createdBy: '',
            endOn: '',
            id: '',
            identifier: '',
            isDisabled: '',
            items: [{
                isDisabled: '',
                tenantType: '',
            }],
            name: '',
            startFrom: '',
            tenantType: '',
            userId: '',
        },
    };
    var init = function () {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            tenantTable = $('#table_Tenants').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: 'API/MultiTenant/Pagged',
                    method: 'POST'
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'name' },
                    { data: 'identifier' },
                    { data: 'connectionString' },
                    {
                        data: 'startFrom',
                        render: function (startFrom) {
                            return $filter('date')(startFrom, 'medium');
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'addedOn',
                        render: function (addedOn) {
                            return $filter('date')(addedOn, 'medium');
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'endOn',
                        render: function (endOn) {
                            return $filter('date')(endOn, 'medium');
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'actions',
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function () {
                            return `<div class="list-icons">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="list-icons-item" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        <i class="icon-menu9"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-item editTenant"><i class="icon-database-edit2"></i>Edit</a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-item deleteTenant"><i class="icon-database-remove"></i>Delete</a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            tenantTable.on('click', '.deleteTenant', function () {
                const $row = $(this).closest('tr');
                const rowData = tenantTable.row($row).data();
                deleteTenant(rowData);
            });
        })
    };

    const onAddEditTenantSubmitForm = function (newTenatForm) {
        if (!state.tenantModel.userId) {
            addTenant(newTenatForm);
        }
        else {
            //updateUser(newUserForm);
        }
    };

    var addTenant = function (newTenatForm) {
        state.isLoading = true;
        TenantServices.addTenant(state.tenantModel).then(
            function () {
                swalInit.fire({
                    title: 'Success',
                    text: 'Tenant has been created',
                    type: 'success'
                });
                userTable.ajax.reload();
                closeModal();
            },
            function (errorResponse) {
                if (errorResponse.status === 400 && errorResponse.data.duplicateRecord) {

                }
                else if (errorResponse.status === 500) {
                    swalInit.fire({
                        title: 'Server Error',
                        text: 'An server error occurred while adding tenant.',
                        type: 'error'
                    });
                }
            }
        )
            .finally(() => state.isLoading = false);
    };  

    var deleteTenant = function (rowObj) {
        state.isLoading = true;
        TenantServices.deleteTenant(rowObj.id).then(
            function () {
                swalInit.fire({
                    title: 'Success',
                    text: 'Tenant Deleted!',
                    type: 'success'
                });
                tenantTable.ajax.reload();
                closeModal();
            },
            function (errorResponse) {
                if (errorResponse.status === 500) {
                    swalInit.fire({
                        title: 'Server Error',
                        text: 'An server error occurred while Deleting Tenant.',
                        type: 'error'
                    });
                }
                else if (errorResponse.status === 404) {
                    swalInit.fire({
                        title: 'Server Error',
                        text: 'Tenant not found on Server.',
                        type: 'error'
                    });
                }
            }
        )
            .finally(() => state.isLoading = false);
    };

    var closeModal = function () {
        if (uibModal) {
            uibModal.close();
        }
    };

    state.onAddEditTenantSubmitForm = onAddEditTenantSubmitForm;
    state.test = test;

    $scope.state = state;
    $scope.init = init;

}]);
```

})();
'''

Comment: is this the function thats not working  onAddEditTenantSubmitForm?

Comment: more like not being invoked by the submit button.

Comment: are you using angularjs right? why you name method like that? it should be $scope.onAddEditTenantSubmitForm = function(){} or if you declare on the top "var vm = this" then vm.onAddEditTenantSubmitForm = function(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the function you are calling on the template via ng-submit to be in your scope and then change the template to call it correctly.

On your controller update your function from a const and tie it to scope

```
$scope.onAddEditTenantSubmitForm = function (newTenatForm) {
```

On your template add "$ctrl." as a prefix to your function

```
 ng-submit="$ctrl.onAddEditTenantSubmitForm(newTenatForm)"
```

Comment: Thanks, That was the mistake. I knew it would something minor that I might have overlooked.